# How to unload resources in AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

I noticed that after closing AndEngine's SimpleBaseGame activity all common activities work very slow and if I launch AndEngine activity again, it works slow too. Seems like there's some data left in memory. I tried to use this:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unloadTextures();
    finish();
}

protected void unloadTextures() {
    for (IEntity entity : objects) {
        if (entity != null) {
            entity.detachSelf();
        }
    }
    for (ITexture atlas : atlases) {
        textureManager.unloadTexture(atlas);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't help. Please, tell me how to unload resources properly? I've found solution for GLES1, but it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, that was my mistake. Seems that once launched Thread keeps running even if object is destroyed. When I stop it manually, everything is ok. If code above wouldn't enough, look here: http://www.andengine.org/forums/post39655.html#p39655